# Auto Suggestion for a searchbox search using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, uisearchbar

I have a searchbox in which as soon as the user hits search word, i  need to do an ajax call and the response needs to be processed and then I can update the search words for user.

i tried to use javascript autocomplete feature but the problem with it is suppose I type the word "abc" in searchbox my function makes the ajax call and it return few suggestions.
if the user stops typing after the ajax call is made and the result has been fetched the autocomplete doesn't display the options available for user.

Here is my code.

```
<input type="text" id="searchBox" value="search" />


function getSuggestions(query){
    SC.get('/search/suggest', { q: query, limit: 10, highlight_mode: 'offsets', linked_partitioning: 1, offset: 0}, function(tracks) {
        if(tracks.length<1){

          return;
        }
        var i = 0;
          tracks.suggestions.forEach(function(track){
            if(track.kind=="track"){              
                suggestList[i] = track.query;
                i++;
            }
          });

          $( "#searchBox" ).autocomplete({
                    source: suggestList
          });
      });
 }
```

This function listens for keyup.

```
$('#searchBox').keyup(function(e){
        var query = $(this).val();
        if(query.length<2)
          return;            
          setTimeout(function() { 
            getSuggestions(query); 
          }, 1000);

    });
```

But as soon as I press one more button if the current result from ajax call mathes the new searchword it will suggest for autocomplete.

I checked few plugins for my luck all of them were expecting the search result in a particular JSON format.

If any one can help me out that would be helpful.

Comment: If I was you, I would have added the timestamp of the last query in memory and  I would have checked if the new result is the latest query. Because your first query could take more time than your latest query. And so, Consequently you will display the wrong query to your user.

Answer (score 1):

If your list of potential suggestions isn't massive, it might be worth pre-fetching it

it's fairly simple to do with typeahead.js (example from link below)

```
$('#input').typeahead([
{
  name: 'countries',
  prefetch: '/countries.json',
}
]);
```

This blog provides an overview of some of its features

https://blog.twitter.com/2013/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me

Comment: It is massive like google. I can't use typeahead. Thanks for answering.